# How to set same code formatting styles to WebStorm and VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, webstorm

Our team uses both VSCode and WebStorm for development, so need to create a same code formatting style for both IDEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend formatting your code with [Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier). There's a plugin for [VSCode](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode) and [WebStorm](https://prettier.io/docs/en/webstorm.html). If you add Prettier as a dependency in `package.json` (with a specific version) you will make sure that both editors invoke the exact same formatting command.

Comment: it will work, but need to configure it properly in both IDEs

Answer (score 0):

You can use [editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/). It's a format for describing code style supported by many editors including WebStorm and VS Code.

Comment: EditorConfig is very surface level, and in practice things like wrapping and indentation behavior differ so much between VS Code and WebStorm, that it's just not enough.